# TensorFlow reshape after text_dataset_from_directory

Tags: python, tensorflow

After the data is loaded with tf.keras.preprocessing.text_dataset_from_directory, the shape is (10, 1). However, the shape needs to be (10,). How could the shape be changed?

```
train_data = tf.keras.preprocessing.text_dataset_from_directory(
    "data/text",
    batch_size=1)

train_features_batch, train_labels_batch = next(iter(train_data.batch(10)))
# (10, 1) (10, 1), but model needs (10,) (10,)
print(train_features_batch.shape, train_labels_batch.shape)


model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(hub.KerasLayer(embedding, input_shape=[], trainable=True))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
```

Comment: Have you tried to use np.squezze() ?

Comment: np.squezze() will work on next(iter(train_data.batch(10))), but the train_data object is passed to model.fit().

Comment: You can [map](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#map) `tf.squeeze()`.

Comment: @Frightera is right, just use  train_data.map(lambda x: tf.squeeze(x))

Comment: `tf.reshape(train_features_batch,shape=(10,))`

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of the community posting the comments of @**Frightera** and @**RishabhGupta**  in the Answer section.

You can use `tf.squeeze()`, which removes dimensions of size 1 from the shape of a tensor like below

```
train_data.map(lambda x: tf.squeeze(x))
```

OR

You can use `tf.reshape()`, which reshapes a tensor like below

```
tf.reshape(train_features_batch,shape=(10,))
```